# Using sed to delete one line after the range of lines

Tags: sed

I have gone through the forums but I haven't found something similar. I have a file in this format.

```
(
        : (yellow_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time (
                          :Time()
                 )                                                                                                        
                :lsm (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
        : (blue_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time (
                          :Time()
                 ) 
                :lsm (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
        : (red_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time (
                          :Time()
                 ) 
                :lsm (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
        : (green_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time (
                          :Time()
                 ) 
                :lsm (false)
                :sofaware (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
)
```

I use the following command to delete the bracket starting with blue,

```
sed '/: (blue/,/:type (pv1_customer)/ {d;p}'
```

But it leaves the trailing parenthesis just a line before red bracket begins. If I use,

```
sed '/: (blue/,/:type (pv1_customer)/ {N;d;p}'
```

It works except the it also removes the red bracket. How can I make it so as to remove only one bracket and clean? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer for original question

As I understand it, you want to delete from the `blue` to the following line that begins with `)`.  This does that:

```
$ sed '/: (blue/,/^[[:space:]]*)/d' input
(
        : (yellow_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time ()
                :lsm (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
        : (red_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time ()
                :lsm (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
        : (green_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time ()
                :lsm (false)
                :sofaware (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
)
```

`/: (blue/` matches the start of the range.  `/^[[:space:]]*)/` matches the end of the range (marked by a line that begins with optional spaces followed by `)`).  `d` tells sed to delete the range.

#### Answer for revised question

In the revised question, there are lines starting with the spaces-close parens pattern that do *not* end our group.  In that case:

```
$ sed '/:type (pv1_customer)/N; /: (blue/,/:type (pv1_customer)/d' input
(
        : (yellow_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time ()
                :lsm (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
        : (red_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time ()
                :lsm (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
        : (green_domain
                :gp_granularity_config_time ()
                :gp_time ()
                :lsm (false)
                :sofaware (false)
                :type (pv1_customer)
        )
)
```

This answer is more like your original approach but has some key changes:

- `/:type (pv1_customer)/N`

  Whenever we find a line that matches `:type (pv1_customer)`, we read in the next line and add it to the pattern space.
- `/: (blue/,/:type (pv1_customer)/d`

  We delete all lines in groups starting with lines that match `: (blue` and ending with lines that match `type (pv1_customer)`.  But, note that since we have already read in the line after the line containing `type (pv1_customer)`, it gets deleted at the same time.

Comment: Hello John, thanks for your prompt answer. I actually deleted some of the text input because it contains confidential info but there are inside the main color_domain brackets lines with closing parenthesis. How can I avoid those? I will change the input message. I will upvote your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @jarr That does make it more interesting.  I added a trick to handle that: see the updated answer.

Comment: That did it!! So in your revised answer, the first part `/:type (pv1_customer)/N`, this gets added to the pattern space automatically. Can you recommend me a good resource where this is explained? Sed indeed has some features.

Comment: My favorite sed tutorial is [Grymoire's](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).  So, to explain in other words, whenever a line matches `:type (pv1_customer)`, the `N` command adds the next line to the pattern space also.  This makes no difference to the output _except_ when the delete `d` command is triggered in the next command.

Answer (score 1):

How about `'/: (blue/,/^  *)$/ d'`?

Comment: Everything gets deleted after the blue pattern. Thanks.

Comment: @jarr You're welcome. I used to do tons of sed/awk. At first, I thought you had a class exercise. But, you mentioned deleting proprietary data, so you're not constrained to sed? Anything more complex than this, and I'd recommend perl/python.

Comment: @Huh??? I posted an answer [that was correct].  OP posted a comment under my answer.  I posted the reply to him, in the _same_ place.  In this context, it's fine, IMO.  I'm not getting your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '/: (/h;G;/\n.*blue_domain/!P;d' file
```

This deletes all lines in the `blue_domain` block, it uses the hold space as a variable which is set on encountering the start of a block i.e. any line containing the string `: (`. Every line has the variable appended to it and only those lines without the `blue_domain` block in the variable are printed.